# Need Use ioreg get USB Serial Number with Python in MacOS?

Tags: python, filter

I try write a small script:

```
import os
os.system("ioreg -p IOUSB -l -b | grep 'USB Serial Number'>> test.txt")
```

result receive in test.txt:

```
"USB Serial Number" = "123456789101213131516"
"USB Serial Number" = "35432"
"USB Serial Number" = "0005663"
```

i want result receive in test.txt:

```
123456789101213131516
35432
0005663
```

I look forward to your support!

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
import os
string='"USB Serial Number" = "123456789101213131516"'
print (string.replace("\"","").split("=")[1])
```